# PTIJ: Why is chazzir rye kosher?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

During Purim I notice that kids (and adults, but mainly kids) eat a lot of *chazzir rye*. To me it looks like junk food rather than bread (usually, when I think of "rye", I think of rye bread), and since I see all types of religious families who keep a kosher home and are strict what children eat, I assume that they are eating kosher food.

But considering that *chazzir* is pig and pigs are not kosher, why would the rye that comes from pigs be kosher? Or is this type of rye similar to bees' honey where even though bees aren't kosher, the honey is?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Adults drink rye.

Comment: @msh210 as do good old boys. and whiskey.

Comment: .. and that was the day the music died.

Comment: And *this* is why I don’t drink on Purim.

Comment: Since the kids have stronger teeth, they can eat sandwiches with the rye bread that their parents can give the excess to their Gentile neighbors for their pigs. As far as their parents' drinking - they have a cup of Rock n Rye, Farewell to you old Southern skies---they're on their way  on their way   on their waaaay!